# save date from date picker into core data

Tags: core-data, swift3, xcode8

i work with swift 3 for macOS and would like to save my date picker value in core data.

I have an attribute (type date) in my entity.
I tried this code for save my date picker value into core date:

```
let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Person", in: context)
let newRecord = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context) as! Person
newRecord.bday = myDatePicker.dateValue as NSDate
```

This value will be save in CoreData:
517935600

is this correct? oO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably. It depends on what date you had selected in the date picker. `NSDate` and `Date` store the date as the number of seconds since a reference date, which is the start of January 1, 2000 UTC. It looks like the UTC value from your date picker was May 31 2017 at 9:00 UTC.

Comment: ahhh okay, and how can i convert it back to an readable date?